# 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I'm trying to create a heatmap using Python on Pycharms. I've this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = pd.read_csv(FILE")

freqMap = {}
for line in data1:
  for item in line:
    if not item in freqMap:
      freqMap[item] = {}

    for other_item in line:
      if not other_item in freqMap:
        freqMap[other_item] = {}

      freqMap[item][other_item] = freqMap[item].get(other_item, 0) + 1
      freqMap[other_item][item] = freqMap[other_item].get(item, 0) + 1

df = data1[freqMap].T.fillna(0)
print(df)
```

My data is stored into a CSV file. Each row represents a sequence of products that are associated by a Consumer Transaction.The typically Basket Market Analysis:

```
99  32  35  45  56  58  7   72
99  45  51  56  58  62  72  17
55  56  58  62  21  99  35  
21  99  44  56  58  7   72  
72  17  99  35  45  56  7   
56  62  72  21  91  99  35  
99  35  55  56  58  62  72  
99  35  51  55  58  7   21  
99  56  58  62  72  21      
55  56  58  21  99  35      
99  35  62  7   17  21      
62  72  21  99  35  58      
56  62  72  99  32  35      
72  17  99  55  56  58
```

When I execute the code, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tst/PycharmProjects/untitled1/tes.py", line 22, in <module>
    df = data1[freqMap].T.fillna(0)
  File "C:\Users\tst\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\tst\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\tst\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1348, in _get_item_cache
    res = cache.get(item)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: @ZachS. many thanks for your response. I try with your statment but I still have the same error :(

Comment: Have you tried: df = data1[freqMap].T.fillna(0)

Comment: What is the output you are trying to get?

Comment: @nicolas.leblanc the error changes :) Many thanks!!!! I'm getting another error :(

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I'm trying to create a HeatMap I didn't put the plot code because the error is before that

Comment: but you are creating a dictionary and not an array.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters What's that means?

Comment: For a heatmap you would usually need an array and then add the values to it. A python dictionary is unsorted, so it's not clear which value belongs to which x/y-value. But perhaps I am misunderstanding your input data.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I've order the CSV and put the row with higher number of columns at first. I've updated the post with a explaination of the input data

Answer (score 2):

You are reading a csv file but it has no header, the delimiter is a space not a comma, and there are a variable number of columns. So that is three mistakes in your first line.

And data1 is a DataFrame, freqMap is a dictionary that is completely unrelated. So it makes no sense to do data1[freqMap].

I suggest you step through this line by line in jupyter or a python  interpreter. Then you can see what each line actually does and experiment.