# 'DataFrame' object is not callable the function

Tags: python, pandas

the code like this, I can get one csv file ,but I get some error:

other answer can't solve my problem.

['DataFrame' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138380/dataframe-object-is-not-callable)

[Dataframe Object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323359/dataframe-object-is-not-callable)

```
import requests,datetime,re,time,pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session=requests.Session()
headers={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.101 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language':'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch'
}

today=datetime.date.today()
yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

url_dict={'SafariPark':'http://ticket.lvmama.com/scenic-100417',
      'Paradise':'http://ticket.lvmama.com/scenic-120604',
      'WaterPark':'http://ticket.lvmama.com/scenic-123120',
      'BirdsPark':'http://ticket.lvmama.com/scenic-104830',
     'InternationalCircus':'http://ticket.lvmama.com/scenic-120603',
      'OceanKingdom':'http://ticket.lvmama.com/scenic-159567',
      'HengqinTheatre':'http://ticket.lvmama.com/scenic-159568',
      'SZHappyValley':'http://ticket.lvmama.com/scenic-104960',
      'SHdisneyrestort':'http://ticket.lvmama.com/scenic-175649',
      'HKdisneyland':'http://ticket.lvmama.com/scenic-105907',
      'Octeast':'http://ticket.lvmama.com/scenic-122400',
      'HKOceanPark':'http://ticket.lvmama.com/scenic-103686'
     }

def get_id(url):
    place_id = url.split('-')[-1]
    return place_id

def get_review(url):
    place_id=get_id(url)
    urls=['http://ticket.lvmama.com/vst_front/comment/newPaginationOfComments?type=all&currentPage={}&totalCount=1&placeId={}&productId=&placeIdType=PLACE&isPicture=&isBest=&isPOI=Y&isELong=N'.format(i,str(place_id)) for i in range(1,6)]
    review_list = []
    for u in urls:
        res=requests.get(u)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
        all_div = soup.find_all('div', {'class', 'comment-li'})
        for t in all_div:
           data = {
                'name': t.select(' div.com-userinfo > p > a')[0].text,
                'date': t.select('div.com-userinfo > p > em')[0].text,
                'review': re.sub('( |\n+|\r+)','',t.find('div', {'class', 'ufeed-content'}).text),
                'tourist_type': t.find('a', {'class', 'com-proTit'}).text,
            }
            review_list.append(data)
    return review_list

def final_data(url):
    review_list=get_review(url)
    df=pandas.DataFrame(review_list)
    data = df[df.date == str(yesterday)]
    if data.empty:
        return 'No review'
    else:
        final_data=data.drop_duplicates()
        return final_data

for name,url in url_dict.items():
    final_data=final_data(url)
    if type(final_data)==str:
        print name+'empty'
     else:
        final_data.to_csv(name+'_{}.csv'.format(yesterday),encoding='utf-8')
            time.sleep(8)
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/project/������ȡ/lvmama.py", line 61, in <module>
    final_data=final_data(url)
 TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: Do you get this error on the second iteration of the `for name,url in url_dict.items():`-loop?

Comment: yes, I only get one csv file.

Comment: You should change name of returning object, for example : `final = final_data(url)`

Comment: yes, It works. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the second iteration, final_data is not considered as a function.
You should change name of returning object.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for name, url in url_dict.items():
        final = final_data(url)
        if type(final) == str:
            print name + 'empty'
        else:
            final.to_csv(name+'_{}.csv'.format(yesterday),encoding='utf-8')
            time.sleep(8)
```